# how to identify if there is a page-break applied on a table row generated in c#?

Tags: c#, html, css, evopdf

i have an application which generates pdf from html using evopdf.

in one scenario the html table generation is done using c# stringbuilder. and i need to include page breaks in tables.
but when i break the table using 'page-break-inside:auto' the border goes missing for the row at the end of each page.
how to show border after page break occurs.

i was initially using 'border-collapse:collapse' in css which was causing the border to go missing at the end of the page. so i changed it to 'border-collapse:separate' and i generated borders using nth-child option to apply single border for cells which fixes the missing border but creates another problem of slightly misaligned borders and it looks weird in pdf when i have merged cells(cells with colspan and rowspan)

i can't break the table manually and include lines since i have no way of identifying logically when to break a table(or when the page is full).

i tried adding box border to table but since table spans across pages it didn't help me.

```
private string GenerateTable(List<MappingRows> mappingRows,TableMetadata metadata)
{
    HtmlTableString.Append("<table class='mapping-table' style='font-size:9px;' width='99%'>");
    HtmlTableString.Append("<thead>");
    HtmlTableString.Append(GenerateHeaderRow(metadata));
    HtmlTableString.Append("</thead>");
    HtmlTableString.Append("<tbody>");
    HtmlTableString.Append("</table>");
    for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
    {
        GenerateRow(MappingRows[i],"#fff")
    }
}
private string GenerateRow(MappingRow MappingRow,string backColor = "")
{
    int maxRowCount = GetMaxRowCountForSection(MappingRow);
    for (int i = 0; i < maxRowCount; i++)
    {
        htmlRowString.Append("<tr>");

        // Source
        if (MappingRow.SourceMappings != null)
        {
            int rowSpan = MappingRow.SourceMappings.Count() >= 1 ? 1 : maxRowCount;
            if (sourceIndex < MappingRow.SourceMappings.Count())
            {
                firstSource = MappingRow.SourceMappings[0];
                string thisSeries = MappingRow.SourceMappings[sourceIndex].Series != null ? MappingRow.SourceMappings[sourceIndex].Series.SeriesName : "";
                if (sourceGroupSeries != thisSeries && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(thisSeries) && !IsComparison)
                {
                    htmlRowString.Append(GenerateCells(MappingRow.SourceMappings[sourceIndex], 1, false, false, true));
                }
                else
                {
                    htmlRowString.Append(GenerateCells(MappingRow.SourceMappings[sourceIndex], string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(thisSeries) ? rowSpan : rowSpan - 1)); // subtract 1 from the rowspan if a group series header took 1 of the rows
                    sourceIndex++;
                }
                sourceGroupSeries = thisSeries;
            }
            else if (rowSpan == 1)
            {
                htmlRowString.Append(GenerateCells(null, rowSpan));
                sourceIndex++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (sourceIndex == 0)
            {
                htmlRowString.Append(GenerateCells(null, maxRowCount));
                sourceIndex = maxRowCount;
            }
        }

        if (i == 0) // first row only
            htmlRowString.Append(AddActionCell(MappingRow.Action, maxRowCount));

        bool isSplitAction = MappingRow.Action == MappingRowActionType.Split;
        // Target A
        if (MappingRow.TargetAMappings != null)
        {
            int rowSpan = MappingRow.TargetAMappings.Count() >= 1 ? 1 : maxRowCount;

            if (targetAIndex < MappingRow.TargetAMappings.Count())
            {
                string thisSeries = MappingRow.TargetAMappings[targetAIndex].Series != null ? MappingRow.TargetAMappings[targetAIndex].Series.SeriesName : "";
                if (targetAGroupSeries != thisSeries && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(thisSeries) && !IsComparison)
                {
                    htmlRowString.Append(GenerateCells(MappingRow.TargetAMappings[targetAIndex], 1, true, false, true));
                }
                else
                {
                    htmlRowString.Append(GenerateCells(MappingRow.TargetAMappings[targetAIndex], string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(thisSeries) ? rowSpan : rowSpan - 0, true, isSplitAction)); // subtract 1 from the rowspan if a group series header took 1 of the rows
                    targetAIndex++;
                }
                targetAGroupSeries = thisSeries;
            }
            else if (rowSpan == 1)
            {
                htmlRowString.Append(GenerateCells(null, rowSpan, true));
                targetAIndex++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (targetAIndex == 0)
            {
                if (MappingRow.Action == MappingRowActionType.Option || MappingRow.Action == MappingRowActionType.Split)
                {
                    htmlRowString.Append(AddCell("", maxRowCount));
                    targetAIndex = maxRowCount;
                    int colSpan = IsIncludeActionText || IsIncludeActionIcons ? TotalColumns - 1 : TotalColumns;
                    for (int x = 0; x < colSpan - 1; x++)
                    {
                        if (x == 0)
                            htmlRowString.Append(AddCell(firstSource.Series == null ? "No recommended  was found" : "No recommended series was found", maxRowCount, true));
                        else
                            htmlRowString.Append(AddCell("", maxRowCount));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    htmlRowString.Append(GenerateCells(null, 1, true));
                }
            }
        }

        // Target B
        if (NumMappingElement > 2)
        {
            if (MappingRow.TargetBMappings != null)
            {
                int rowSpan = MappingRow.TargetBMappings.Count() > 1 ? 1 : maxRowCount;

                if (targetBIndex < MappingRow.TargetBMappings.Count())
                {
                    string thisSeries = MappingRow.TargetBMappings[targetBIndex].Series != null ? MappingRow.TargetBMappings[targetBIndex].Series.SeriesName : "";
                    if (targetBGroupSeries != thisSeries && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(thisSeries) && !IsComparison)
                    {
                        htmlRowString.Append(GenerateCells(MappingRow.TargetBMappings[targetBIndex], 1, true, false, true));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        htmlRowString.Append(GenerateCells(MappingRow.TargetBMappings[targetBIndex], string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(thisSeries) ? rowSpan : rowSpan - 0, true, isSplitAction)); // subtract 1 from the rowspan if a group series header took 1 of the rows
                        targetBIndex++;
                    }
                    targetBGroupSeries = thisSeries;
                }
                else if (rowSpan == 1)
                {
                    htmlRowString.Append(GenerateCells(null, rowSpan, true));
                    targetBIndex++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (targetBIndex == 0)
                {
                    if (MappingRow.Action == MappingRowActionType.Option || MappingRow.Action == MappingRowActionType.Split)
                    {
                        htmlRowString.Append(AddCell("", maxRowCount));
                        targetBIndex = maxRowCount;
                        int colSpan = IsIncludeActionText || IsIncludeActionIcons ? TotalColumns - 1 : TotalColumns;
                        for (int x = 0; x < colSpan - 1; x++)
                        {
                            if (x == 0)
                                htmlRowString.Append(AddCell(firstSource.Series == null ? "No recommended  was found" : "No recommended series was found", maxRowCount, true));
                            else
                                htmlRowString.Append(AddCell("", maxRowCount));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        htmlRowString.Append(GenerateCells(null, 1, true));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        htmlRowString.Append("</tr>");
    }
}

private string GenerateCells(Mapping mp, int rowSpan = 1, bool IsTarget = false, bool IsSplitAction = false, bool IsGroupSeries = false)
{
    //logic to generate data for each cell in a section of the row based on mapping metadata and add cells(td) with rowspan and colspan
    //here i can use inline style or a CSS to apply formatting options

    // calls AddCell(string innerHtml, int rowSpan, bool IsName = false, bool isSeriesHeader = false, string backcolor = "")
    // which is a plain stringbuilder which forms 'td' with the given inner html and options
}
```

and CSS here

```
table.mapping-table {  padding: 0; border-collapse:separate;page-break-inside:auto !important;
                        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;color: #222;}
table.mapping-table tr td .no-border { border:0px solid #fff !important; }                        
.no-border { border:0px solid #fff !important;  }                        
table.mapping-table tr td .black-border-top { border-top:1px solid !important; }                        
table.mapping-table .black-border-right { border-right:1px solid ; }                        
table.mapping-table .black-border-left-top { border-left:1px solid ; border-top:1px solid ; }
table.mapping-table .black-border-right-top { border-right:1px solid; border-top:1px solid; }
table.mapping-table .black-border-top { border-top:1px solid ; }
table.mapping-table .black-border-bottom { border-bottom:1px solid !important; }
table.mapping-table .black-border-left-bottom { border-left:1px solid !important; border-bottom:1px solid !important; }
table.mapping-table .black-border-right-bottom { border-right:1px solid !important; border-bottom:1px solid !important; }
table.mapping-table tr .title-row {  font-size:9px !important;}
table.mapping-table .title-row td { border:1px solid white; text-align:center; background-color:#183063; color:White }
table.mapping-table tr .title-row1 {  font-size:9px !important;}
table.mapping-table .title-row1 td {  text-align:center; background-color:#183063; color:White }
table.mapping-table .sector-category-row td {  text-align:left; background-color:#688db1; color:White; font-weight:bold; }
table.mapping-table .asset-class-row td { text-align:left; background-color:#e7f3ff; color:#333; font-weight:bold; padding-left:18px; }
table.mapping-table .white-space { border:0px solid #fff !important;}
table.mapping-table tr {
    page-break-inside:avoid !important;
}
table.mapping-table tr td {
    border-right:1px solid;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
table.mapping-table tr:nth-child(0) td {
    border-top:1px solid;
}
table.mapping-table tr td:nth-child(1) {
    border-left:1px solid;
}


table.mapping-table .np { padding:0 !important } /* No Padding. Short name for Html output optimization. */
table.nb { width:100% !important; border:0px solid #fff !important; white-space: nowrap;} /* No Border. Short name for Html output optimization. */
table.mapping-table .textAlignLeft { text-align:left; }
table.mapping-table .letterspacing { letter-spacing: .1em; }
```

refer below screenshot for how it'll look.i need to show border in the end highlighted with yellow.i should use only html and css
[image: sample pdf -- i need border highlighted in yellow box]

Comment: You need to add [mcve] there should be nothing "insecure" about html and css that you can not share. Without any code, I'm pretty sure nobody can help you.

Comment: Everybody can add code. Just make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without the privat data.